# How is the Union Type derived in LLVM

Tags: llvm, unions

```
union u{
 char ch[41];
 int b[10];  
}un;
```

The LLVM compiles to this

```
%union.u = type { [10 x i32], [4 x i8] }
```

and this

```
union un{
  struct s{
    int a;
    float f;
    double d;
  }st;

  int intArr[10];
}uno;
```

compiles to this

```
%union.un = type { %struct.s, [24 x i8] }
%struct.s = type { i32, float, double }
```

Can any one explain how the union type is derived ?

Answer (score 4):

The first member is just the most aligned member of the union (it arbitrarily picks one if there are multiple such members), and an array of i8 is appended to make it the right size.

Comment: what do you mean by most aligned member ? Does it mean the member whose alignment numerical value is more or what ? In the following case what should be the most aligned member of the union double or int array

union def
{
 int x[2][2];
 double d;
};