# create struct and union type in llvmIR using C++ API

Tags: api, struct, llvm, union

In order to save different types(str or double) of values in a non-typed var in my language,I need a struct like:

```
Struct BaseVarStruct{
         bool _isString;
         union {
         string _sVal;
         double _dVal;
         }_val;
};
```

I try to use StructType* BaseVarType=StructType::create("basevar",type::getInt1Ty(),???),but i dont't know for sure it's a literal or not.In offical class ref,There's a class called"UnionType",but i can't find it .MAYBE union type is not supported in LLVM now？or maybe i can define union type by StructType and give all members a same offset?

Answer (score 1):

The LLVM IR used to have a union type - which was essentially a struct with all fields at offset 0 - but it no longer does (removed in version 2.8). I believe that compiling any language with dynamic types or unions into the strongly-typed IR will require adding bitcasts.

So you could find the requires alignment and create a struct with the fields to fit it (see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742109/how-is-the-union-type-derived-in-llvm) on how Clang does it), then branch based on `_isString`, and in each branch target perform a different bitcast. Alternatively, if you know the type expected of the union at each point it is used, you could encode that information in metadata instead of a field, and then compile the the access to the union based on the metadata.